# How to fix the error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (2,)?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have to plot a diagram that does a curvefitting for the following formula:

```
2*np.pi*np.sqrt((lx/g)*1+1/16*a**2)
```

Problem is that it gives me a matrix and thus the plotting doesn't work anymore if I interpret the following error correctly:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,) (2,)

here is also the code that I have used so far:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
##defining function of mathematical pendulum
my_data =genfromtxt('lundd_3.csv',delimiter=',',skip_header=1)
##defining my variables
lx=my_data[:,0].reshape(1,-1).flatten()
ty=my_data[:,1]
Xerr=my_data[:,2]
Yerr=my_data[:,3]
a=my_data[:,4]

def mathPen(lx,a,g):
##here must be the error because it somehow creates here the matrix but I don't know why??
    return 2*np.pi*np.sqrt((lx/g)*1+1/16*a**2)
Fit=curve_fit(mathPen, lx, ty)
fitParameter = Fit[0]
fehlerMatrix = Fit[1]


##defining variable again
g = fitParameter
##creating new values
xFunk = np.linspace(np.min(lx),np.max(lx),100)
print(xFunk)

yFunk = mathPen(xFunk,a,g)

plt.plot(xFunk,yFunk)
plt.plot(lx,ty,markers='x',linestyle = 'none',color='blue')
plt.show()
```

And now follows the errorcode and it shows me that the error must be in the function.
**
So is there a way to rewrite the function so I don't get a matrix or can I somehow reshape the values so that they can be plotted? **

I've tried to reshape the new xFunk Values with the np.reshape function and also have tried it with the flatten function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "And to be honest, I am really done with this problem because it is due on Tuesday." This is [not our problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569). "So is there a way to rewrite the function so I don't get a matrix or can I somehow reshape the values so that they can be plotted?" The error message tells you directly: you are trying to use two one-dimensional arrays. One of them has 2 elements, and the other has 100. You should start by figuring out which operation in that line causes the problem and what the arrays are and why they are that size.

Comment: That part generally is your responsibility; we do not "find the bug" for you, but instead expect you to produce a [mre] first as a result of [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code.

Comment: Hii okay, thank you so much first of all. I am new to python, and as far as I understood, does the np.sqrt() function give you a 2d output in this case?

Comment: "does the np.sqrt() function give you a 2d output " Well, did you **try it**?

Comment: what is the output of `(lx/g)*1+1/16*a**2`? please put it in the question

Comment: I just tried it again and I get as an output the following:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (2,)

Comment: post each of the values individually like 
print(lx)
print(g)
print(a)
in the question itself. hard to understand whats going on without more info.

Comment: Okay, I just thought that it is maybe because I have still lx instead of xFunk in there it didn't work, but that was wrong. And I have also tried it with reshaping all of the input data

Comment: I have for the print(lx)
[0.5555 0.4445 0.3215 0.2025 0.0875 0.4225]
print(tx):
[1.5308 1.3452 1.1772 0.9252 0.5964 1.3428]
print(a)
[0.17 0.17 0.17 0.17 0.17 0.17]

g is being calculated and there I have as values: 
Parameter 2 : 9.388685078012687 <- 0.11517856314326509

Comment: Hii, just wanted to let everybody know that I found the error. It took g with 2 different parameters and I just had to say, which parameter it should take and now it has been able to plot it.